# Winforms DataGridView resizing issue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm not 100% sure how I should word this question but I'll try my best.

I have a PointCtrlForm that has a DataGridView inside a TableLayoutPanel. The DataGridView is docked to the table as Fill. PointCtrlForm is docked to another window set as MDIParent with the dockstyle property set as Fill.

Resizing the main window properly resizes the PointCtrlForm, which then is supposed to resize the DataGridView as well. Well, at least "half" of the resizing works properly. Enlarging the main window also enlarges the datagridview, which is what I expected but if I shrink the main window to a certain point, the DataGridView stops shrinking and hides the columns without showing a scrollbar.

I've checked that all columns do not have Frozen property enabled, checked that both the datagridview and the child window is properly docked, and checked the scrollbars property is set to both.

Edit: AutoSizeColumnsMode is also fill.

I'll post the content of the Designer.cs here. I'd appreciate any guidance.

```
namespace DDCUI
{
    partial class PointCtrlForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
            this.CmbSubDevice = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.BtnBack = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CmbMainDevice = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.BtnRefresh = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.ID = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.PointName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Value = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Description = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.DefaultValue = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.ActiveString = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.InactiveString = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.AlarmCondition = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tableLayoutPanel1
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 6;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 151F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 88F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.CmbSubDevice, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnBack, 0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.CmbMainDevice, 0, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1, 0, 2);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.BtnRefresh, 4, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.label1, 5, 1);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 67.02128F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 32.97872F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 368F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(639, 467);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // CmbSubDevice
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.CmbSubDevice, 2);
            this.CmbSubDevice.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.CmbSubDevice.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("굴림", 12F);
            this.CmbSubDevice.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.CmbSubDevice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(203, 69);
            this.CmbSubDevice.Name = "CmbSubDevice";
            this.CmbSubDevice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 24);
            this.CmbSubDevice.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // BtnBack
            // 
            this.BtnBack.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
            this.BtnBack.Name = "BtnBack";
            this.BtnBack.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 54);
            this.BtnBack.TabIndex = 0;
            this.BtnBack.Text = "Back";
            this.BtnBack.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.BtnBack.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtnBack_Click);
            // 
            // CmbMainDevice
            // 
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.CmbMainDevice, 2);
            this.CmbMainDevice.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.CmbMainDevice.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("굴림", 12F);
            this.CmbMainDevice.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.CmbMainDevice.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "I/O",
            "VIRTUAL",
            "SAC",
            "MODBUS",
            "NATIONAL",
            "TOSHIBA",
            "SCHEDULE",
            "SYSTEM ALARM",
            "LOGIC",
            "GROUP"});
            this.CmbMainDevice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 69);
            this.CmbMainDevice.Name = "CmbMainDevice";
            this.CmbMainDevice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(194, 24);
            this.CmbMainDevice.TabIndex = 2;
            this.CmbMainDevice.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CmbMainDevice_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.ID,
            this.PointName,
            this.Value,
            this.Description,
            this.DefaultValue,
            this.ActiveString,
            this.InactiveString,
            this.AlarmCondition});
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.dataGridView1, 6);
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 101);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 23;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(633, 363);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // BtnRefresh
            // 
            this.BtnRefresh.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(403, 69);
            this.BtnRefresh.Name = "BtnRefresh";
            this.BtnRefresh.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 26);
            this.BtnRefresh.TabIndex = 6;
            this.BtnRefresh.Text = "Refresh";
            this.BtnRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("굴림", 12F);
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(554, 66);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 32);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 7;
            this.label1.Text = "XXX 개";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // ID
            // 
            this.ID.FillWeight = 70F;
            this.ID.HeaderText = "ID";
            this.ID.Name = "ID";
            // 
            // PointName
            // 
            this.PointName.FillWeight = 70F;
            this.PointName.HeaderText = "이름";
            this.PointName.Name = "PointName";
            // 
            // Value
            // 
            this.Value.FillWeight = 70F;
            this.Value.HeaderText = "값";
            this.Value.Name = "Value";
            // 
            // Description
            // 
            this.Description.FillWeight = 70F;
            this.Description.HeaderText = "설명";
            this.Description.Name = "Description";
            // 
            // DefaultValue
            // 
            this.DefaultValue.FillWeight = 70F;
            this.DefaultValue.HeaderText = "초기값";
            this.DefaultValue.Name = "DefaultValue";
            // 
            // ActiveString
            // 
            this.ActiveString.HeaderText = "Active문자열";
            this.ActiveString.Name = "ActiveString";
            // 
            // InactiveString
            // 
            this.InactiveString.HeaderText = "InActive문자열";
            this.InactiveString.Name = "InactiveString";
            // 
            // AlarmCondition
            // 
            this.AlarmCondition.HeaderText = "알람조건";
            this.AlarmCondition.Name = "AlarmCondition";
            // 
            // PointCtrlForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 12F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(639, 467);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "PointCtrlForm";
            this.Text = "LG-DDC";
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BtnBack;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox CmbMainDevice;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox CmbSubDevice;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button BtnRefresh;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ID;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PointName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Value;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Description;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn DefaultValue;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ActiveString;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn InactiveString;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn AlarmCondition;

    }
}
```

Comment: try `this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;` in mdi child form_load. just check it once. I dont have very good command on windows

Comment: When I tried that, it makes everything on the child form (including DataGridView) disappear upon resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution and it's rather simple.

The row and column sizes for the DGV has to be set "percentage (relative)" not "absolute" in order for the docking to work properly.

You can edit the sizes by right clicking on one of the cells of the DGV and clicking on Edit Row/Column Properties.

Comment: I don't see the setting you're changing?