# flowlayout panel not shrinking when parent form size is changed

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a form with a flowlayout panel [autosize : true, Grow and Shrink mode].
this panel will hold a user control, which has a tablelayoutpanel [autosize : true, Grow and Shrink mode]..I have a datagrid inside the tablelayoutpanel.

the problem is, if I shrink the form, the flowlayout panel is not shrinking with the form.
I need to have the panel shrink-ed with the form, so that there is no scroll on the datagrid.

is there a way to shrink the panel along with the parent form? I tried docking, still no use.
any help on this will be of real use!

Comment: Clearly you don't actually like AutoSize = true for the flow layout panel.  So don't use it.

Comment: I can do the same for tablelayoutpanel..not sure why flowlayoutpanel behaves differently....

Comment: Related, but perhaps not the same:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076810/winforms-datagridview-resizing-issue