# DataGridView acts as though it has a minimum size inside a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

When I place a data grid view on a form, with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill`, I can shrink the form down to less than one row remaining before there are any issues with the data grid view scroll bar.  However if I place it inside a table layout panel that is in turn docked to the form, the data grid view starts to act as though it has a minimum height, cutting off the bottom rows and bottom of the scroll bar.

[image: Form after Resizing]

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingList<Widget> list = new BindingList<Widget>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Widget { MyProperty = i });
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 20F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 30F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(976, 518);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

I tried adding `this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;` which showed it was the data grid that was not resizing, the panel scroll bar was correctly placed and not cut off.

Similar questions without an answer that worked for me:

- [flowlayout panel not shrinking when parent form size is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206594/flowlayout-panel-not-shrinking-when-parent-form-size-is-changed)
- [Winforms DataGridView resizing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076810/winforms-datagridview-resizing-issue)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this error?  I copied your exact code and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: You have to resize the window to see the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I missed that.  Time to debug.

Comment: That's just the starting size.  ClientSize changes dynamically when you resize the window.  (Checked by adding handler for form Resize event.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in `InitializeComponent` and it should allow the grid to shrink to nothing, letting the scrollbars show as intended.

```
this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
```

Comment: That worked!  I'd already tried doing the same with MinimumSize to no effect, didn't occur to me to try Size, as that is supposed to change dynamically with the Dock.

Comment: I did the same as you.  I don't know why this solution works or why Size acts like a minimum in this case, but I'm glad it solved it for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works for the simplified case, but my main app is still having issues.  I'll have to try to work out a new minimal repeatable example.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by wrapping the datagridview inside a panel before putting it in the tablelayoutpanel.

Strangely this doesn't happen to all the datagridviews that I put into tablelayoutpanels.

Comment: This should be comment