# Completely resize DataGridView in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am having issues resizing a DataGridView in a VB.NET application.  The DataGridView is not bound to a data source, as all data is entered into it manually.

It is currently docked in a TableLayoutPanel, set to `Fill`, and I would expect it to automatically resize to fit its assigned cell, but it seems to have a minimum size, at which I can not shrink it any further.  This is a problem because the tablet PC I am deploying to has a much smaller resolution, so the Windows must scale properly.  The TableLayoutPanels are keeping everything in the correct position, but it is crucial that my grids scale as well so that the end user can see the bottom scroll bar and all the records in the table.

This problem is pretty much the same as the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076810/winforms-datagridview-resizing-issue).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle in the properties window of the datagridviewer there is Padding feature that defaults to 0,0,0,0 which represents each direction. Perhaps if you reduce the padding it will autosize up instead of being limited on the upper end moving down.

Comment: The padding does not allow negative values, they seem to default back to zero.

Comment: Instead of using ".Fill" you may want to consider ".AllCells" in the columns properties. The fill size and weight becomes irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AutoSizeMode` and `FillWeight` properties of columns in your datagridview

```
'Column 1
Dim columnindex As Int32 = Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("One", "One")
With Me.DataGridView1.Columns(columnindex)
    .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    .FillWeight = 80 'This can be used as percent value for column width
End With

'Column 2
columnindex = Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Two", "Two")
With Me.DataGridView1.Columns(columnindex)
    .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    .FillWeight = 20 
End With

Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add({"sample text", "1"})
Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add({"another sample text", "2"})
```